# Get a point for part of Quadratic Bezier Curve

Tags: calculus, curves, bezier-curve

Given a Quadratic Bezier Curve $a$ defined with three points $A$, $Q$, and $B$.
[image]

Then given a point $P$ such that $P\in a$. The task is to find such a Quadratic Bezier Curve $b$ that is defined by points $A$, $K$, and $P$ (where $K$ is some unknown control point) and any of the points of this curve is a point of $a$ curve.
[image]

Could anyone please suggest a way to determine the point K, if all other points are given?

Comment: The key term is *subdivision*. See for instance https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-sub.html

Comment: Thank you, it might help!